# How Can I grow from this?

Tags: stoicism

Everything that's unpleasant makes me upset, I know that's the sign of weakness. How can I master my emotions? How can I grow from this?

Comment: Stoicism is a good path which is a philosophical approach to finding [ataraxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataraxia). There's also [exposure response therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_therapy) which is a scientific approach. I've voted to close because this question is a bit too broad for the Q&A approach here. If you do a search for 'stoicism', you'll have some good examples for additional questions.

Comment: Oh, and I would point you in the direction of Goleman's various works like [this one on emotional intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_Intelligence). It's good to have a scientific model in your head of how the brain works and how your mind relates.

Comment: Pretty vague question. I think of the Japanese tea ceremony though, which inspired Heidegger's 'dasein'. Meditation in a sense creates a circumstance with nothing objectively objectionable, so that that the mind can experience itself. Seung Sahn said meditation in a Himalayan ice-cave is like training-wheels, our real goal is to be able to keep meditative mind on Main St New York. That is, we can control our conditions, use that to learn about our mind, & learn to cultivate the qualities of our mind. The world cannot give you peace, you must find it. So seek out conditions to make it familiar

Comment: It's ironic that this question would be closed as off-topic, when some philosophers would consider personal growth and mastering one's emotions to be the purpose of philosophy.

Comment: "sign of weakness" I don't think that is a good concept. The reed is 'weak' in the storm, the oak is strong but falls. Adapting to circumstance, while maintaining inner purpose, is far better than idealising any particular habit. https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1181961-pepe-the-frog

Comment: @causative: I voted reopen

Comment: This might get more useful answers if posed as "What noteworthy works of philosophy are widely considered to be useful for learning to keep one's cool when unpleasant things happen?"